# Administrative boundaries worldwide

Tags: shapefile, administrative-boundaries

I am searching for a downloadable database of administrative boundary shapes, best would be worldwide data.

I have found [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/) but it seems a bit outdated, also the [OSM site defining the administrative boundaries](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aboundary=administrative) seems interesting but I haven't found any exports based on this definition.

The detail level of the shapes is not that important as it would be used to let a user select the city/region (if not in a city or no data for that city available). A hierachical representation like Country > Region > City would be great.